# No signature of method: org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.JanusGraphIndexWrapper.buildCompositeIndex()

Tags: titan, janusgraph, gremlin-server, janus

I am trying to create a database schema in janusgraph(latest version) which is using cassandra(version 3). But am stuck with the following error

```
No signature of method: org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.JanusGraphIndexWrapper.buildCompositeIndex()
```

This is my sample code:

```
m = graph.openManagement()
Employee = m.makeVertexLabel('Employee').make()
callingName = m.makePropertyKey('callingName').dataType(String.class).make()
m.buildIndex('callingNameByEmployee', Vertex.class).addKey(callingName,Mapping.TEXT.asParameter()).buildMixedIndex('search')
```

As per the official documentation above code seems to be correct but I don't know what is going wrong.

**Note:
It is working with the old version of janusgraph(i.e, 0.3.1), It is not working the latest version (i.e, 0.4.1)**